# Getting CSS file by ID to manipulate the properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following snippet that overwrites certain CSS properties:-

```
var styleSheet  = document.styleSheets[2]; // refers to the 3rd stylesheet

// Mozilla
if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
    var cssRule     = styleSheet.cssRules;

    // ... do something
}
// IE
else {
    var cssRule     = styleSheet.rules;

    // ... do something
}
```

This code works, but I don't like the fact that I'm referencing the stylesheet using `document.styleSheets[2]` because it is brittle. So, I assigned an `id` to the `link` tag, hoping that I can use JQuery to easily get that stylesheet by id. However, I'm not sure how to cast the returned object from JQuery into a `CSSStyleSheet` object so that I can assign it to `styleSheet` variable.

```
// I want to change this...
var styleSheet  = document.styleSheets[2]; // [object CSSStyleSheet]

// ... to something like this...
var styleSheet  = $("link#layout"); // not right because it is a [object Object]
```

Any clue? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Per @TJ's suggestion, after futzing around, I think I might go with `title` instead of `href`... at least for now until I find any incompatibilities next time. Right now, this works in FF, IE, Safari and Chrome.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; ++i) {
    var styleSheet  = document.styleSheets[i]; 

    if (document.styleSheets[i].title == "layout-overwrite") {
        // Mozilla
        if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
            var cssRule = styleSheet.cssRules;
            // .. do something
        }
        // IE
        else {
            var cssRule = styleSheet.rules;
            // .. do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you'll get back for that `id` will be the `link` DOM element, not the stylesheet.

As far as I know, there's no way to assign a name to a stylesheet and then look it up by that name. Instead, you'll need to define a "marker rule" (unless you already have a nice unique rule you can look for), loop through the style sheet objects, and look for that rule to determine that you've found the right one.

**Edit**: Both MDC and MSDN say there's an `href` property on their [`CSSStyleSheet` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/stylesheet) / [`styleSheet` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which would be even better than a marker rule.

**Edit 2**: And it (the `href`) seems to work in IE, FF, Chrome, and Opera, although I'm getting duplicate entries for the specific stylesheet I tested with: http://jsbin.com/edaga3/2
(Off-topic: Also note that if you load a stylesheet from a different origin, your browser may prevent access to the rules.)

Comment: you can't access `.cssRules` with firebug console, can you ?

Comment: @jAndy: Not following you. With the specific linked example above, I can't with Firebug, no; I get a security violation. Don't know if that's a cross-domain issue or what.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yes that's what I'm wondering, security violation when accessing.

Comment: It was cross-domain stuff, just tested with a non-cross-domain example and Firebug was happy. See the updated link.

Comment: @TJ: Thanks much. It seems like it might be even better if I use `title` instead of `href`. The problem with `href` is it returns absolute URL, and if I were to deploy this project in multiple environment, then I have to do string matching. With `title`, I just need to assign a meaningful name to the `link` tag. I tested `document.styleSheets[i].title` and it seems to work in FF, IE, Safari and Chrome.

Comment: @T.J.Crowser: you're not accessing `.cssRules` in the example. Doesn't work either there for me.

Comment: @limc: Good deal. @jAndy: I'm not following you on the `cssRules` stuff. The OP already knows he can access those (issues with not being able to access them were X-domain because my original example used jQuery UI's CSS files -- they were to hand). I'm guessing he's not doing x-domain.

Answer (score 0):

native js assuming your link tag as the ID of 'css'

```
document.querySelectorAll('link#css')[0].sheet;
```